# Repeat only some of the rows in THEAD when printing multi-page table in HTML

Tags: html, css

I need to do this trick while ***printing*** huge HTML tables:

```
+-----+---------+-----+
|  ID |  Title  | Qty |  ⇐ descriptive header that shouldn't repeat
+-----+---------+-----+
|  1  |    2    |  3  |  ⇐ column number that **SHOULD** repeat
+-----+---------+-----+
| aaa | bbb     |   0 |  ⇐ data; rows upon rows of data

  ...     ...     ...

+-----+---------+-----+
|  1  |    2    |  3  |  ⇐ page 2
+-----+---------+-----+
| xxx | yyy     | 999 |
  ...     ...     ...
```

Is it possible to implement without resorting to "2 tables with fixed layout" solution (I **really** don't want to use fixed values)? Oh, and I can only use HTML and CSS.

If it helps, I only target IE (6 and up).

### More info

So far, I've tried these different hacks, but to no avail:

1. no `thead`, second row gets `th` instead of `td`

   1.1. even with `style="display:table-header-group"` on that `tr`
2. in `thead`, using `td` instead of `th` for the first row

   2.1. using `style="display:table-row-group"` on `thead` and `style="display:table-header-group"` on the second row in it
3. variations of inserting `thead` in the middle of `tbody` (as per one of the answers that disappeared)

I'm starting to accept that it isn't possible and that I'll have to resort to that fixed layout setup (but I pray that leaving only one flexible-width column will be enough) :-(

Comment: Note: It's never `only` when it comes to `IE6`.

Comment: will your second table be on another web page? I don't really understand your question

Comment: @BumbleB2na This is relevant for printing. Or for devices that work with pages. Like an eBook reader.

Comment: @BumbleB2na, this is a single web page which should be nicely paginated for printing.

Comment: I'm officially interested by this question. I tried a few approaches, but couldn't find anything to work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As it turns out, you can't do this kind of thing.

The closest solution depending on your requirement will be to use two fixed-layout tables upon each other OR to hard-break the table in parts guaranteed to be fitting on one page.

Answer (score 2):

Support is still rare, but you can do this with the right renderer:

**Dcoumentation**:
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/
and
http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-gcpm/

**Popular Engines with support**:
http://weasyprint.org/docs/features/
and
http://www.princexml.com/doc/9.0/page-headers-footers/

I'm also working to get support included in **[WKHTMLTOPDF](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf)**

Answer (score 1):

Based on the idea that you want this table to flow nicely on to separate "pages" on a device's screen (I still don't follow exactly what you mean by that), I would go with [paginating your single table with javascript](http://en.newinstance.it/2006/09/27/client-side-html-table-pagination-with-javascript/).

For your 2nd header in the first page of your table, I would use javascript to insert an extra row at the beginning of the table, give the  a class  and add in the column numbers programatically. I can expand on this if you need me to.

Comment: I make a transformation stylesheet to visualize some xml, which in turn should be printable according to template sealed by standards. Due to some limitations, I can't use scripts or anything besides pure html and css.